# Collect Service Fabric Cluster logs in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-service-fabric, service-factory

I am new to Service Fabric Cluster and I am trying to collect logs from my cluster in Azure.

Basically, I have an event source "XXXXX" defined in ServiceEventSource.cs. Locally, when I add this source to the ETW Providers in the Diagnostics Events view in VS2015, it shows correctly the logs.

In Azure, I am unable to collect any logs. When I created my cluster, 5 storage accounts have been added but I am unable to see logs in the stored blobs.
I tried to edit the template.json file based on [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/). I added an entry in `EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration` :

```
"EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [
     {
         "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
         "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
         "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
         "DefaultEvents": {
             "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"
         }
     },
     {
        "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
        "DefaultEvents": {
          "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
         }
     },
     {
        "provider": "XXXXX",
        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
        "DefaultEvents": {
          "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
         }
     }
],
```

Then I deployed this modified template but I am still unable to collect logs.

Any help would be very appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: So, is it working locally?

Comment: I have no experience in this question specifically because we've tied our application into AppInsights and wrapped our etw sources to also send metrics to AI. Not a true answer, but perhaps something to consider as the aggregation and graphing in app insights is pretty decent.

Comment: Did you see this page about collecting logs from vm's? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-diagnostics-template/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the logs in Azure.

The destination is specified in the template : `"eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"` and this is stored in a table in a storage account specified in the template too.